# Quick OpenGL - Build a House and an eye

Tags: opengl

I have very limited coding knowledge of OpenGL/Glut.  I'm supposed to build house and a blinking eye. Now I have googled and tried the "quick solution" but I cannot find. I want a fast paced tutorial to get me into advanced concepts. Please help me to get that kind of tutorial. little introduction and explanation and much in advanced concept. Also if there is code I can learn from I will appreciate.

I'm comfortable with C/C++ and little OpenGL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick solution is: Model the house and the eye in a 3D modeller, like Blender. Export the meshes and index arrays into C arrays. Write the code to load the meshed into a Vertex Array / Vertex Buffer Object and a draw-event handler function that binds the vertex array and calls glDrawElements on the index array.

Implement the blinking by building the eyelid from two meshes that can rotate around some axis that makes it look like blinking.

OpenGL is just a drawing API. It has no modelling functions. It just pushes triangles to the screen. Any homework assignment to "code a modell" is misguided and the person who handed out the assignment has no clue about it.

Comment: That is great! But as beginner in OGL thing, I cannot understand what you mean by meshes. Also I dont know how to model things in Blender. Any Quick start tutorial on those things is appreciated. Thanks for pointing to that!

Comment: A mesh is an array of vertices and a list of index-tripplets/quadruplets that form a mesh of triangles and/or quads of the vertices.

Comment: datenwolf, quoting wikipedia on GLU they say "GLU is a computer graphics library. It consists of a number of functions that use the base OpenGL library to provide higher-level drawing routines from the more primitive routines that OpenGL provides. It is usually distributed with the base OpenGL package.

Among these features are mapping between screen- and world-coordinates, generation of texture mipmaps, drawing of quadric surfaces, NURBS, tessellation of polygonal primitives."
Does that means I can somehow use GLU to do what you described above or I just misunderstood the whole thing?

Comment: @Stefano: Well, in principle and with a lot of patience yes. But GLU is so outdated, that its smell is unbearable. GLU just provides very, very basic shapes like spheres or cones. NURBS patches could be used for the eye, but you'd still need to model them, because "coding" NURBS is a sure way to insanity.

Comment: Ok, I have decided I will go for Blender and OGL. I have just googled and found that there is issue with file format to export. I would like to hear your opinion on which file format is easiest. Thanks for invaluable contribution

Comment: @Stefano: The easiest would be to export into C arrays that you statically link with your program. That way yu save writing a file parser.

Comment: Thanks,
I was off for a while. I will check how to export C arrays with blender

Comment: I have decided to mark this as solution, and I will ask as new question any issue that arises with actual loading of blender models

Answer (score 3):

For some OpenGL tutorials that are not hopelessly out of date, try:

- http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/
- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

[This question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926357/c-opengl-books/5935977#5935977) may also be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately the arcsynthesis.org tutorials are not complete (yet).

Comment: True, but I felt it still deserved some publicity, if only because it really helped me as a beginner wanting to learn modern OpenGL ! I hope it does get completed because it is one of the best OpenGL ressources I've read so far, and that includes the latest editions of the Superbible and Orange book.

Comment: Bethor, I like especially the one at opengl-tutorial as I can download to read even offline :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a great crash course in OpenGL programming, work through the tutorials on http://nehe.gamedev.net/.

Comment: Nehe is badly outdated, relying heavily (if not entirely) on functionality deprecated in OpenGL 3.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I read somewhere that those tutorials are out of date. I will check, though I want to be sure they are at least applicable before I waste time and find they are useless. Just assurance. and thanks again!

Comment: To clarify, if you need to learn "the old ways" (i.e. fixed-function pipeline, for compatibility with by now relatively ancient hardware), Nehe is probably the standard way to go. As an introduction to how any modern 3D engine is going to work, though, it is so out of date that it will probably hurt you more than it will help.

Comment: @Bethor I did not realize that. It's been quite a while since I've done any OpenGL. I just remember it being a great resource. It's a shame it's fallen out of date...